# How to fetch data from database in table at every 15 minute?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql

I had store 8 days data in mysql database. I want to retrieve those data in jsp page at every 15 minute . please give some hint to resolve my problem..

Comment: Can you use a jquery to poll the DB every 15mins?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Do your XHR request here
    console.log("I'm going to get me some data");
}, 900000);
```

jQuery's .get, .post or .ajax will make the XHR request easy.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to create meta refresh in header of JSP.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

For fetching data use:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Fetching Data From a Database</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>Database Lookup</H1>
    <FORM ACTION="self.jsp" METHOD="POST">
        Please enter the ID of the publisher you want to find:
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="id">
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
    </FORM>


    <H1>Fetching Data From a Database</H1>

    <% 
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:odbc:data", "userName", "password");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String id = request.getParameter("id");  

        ResultSet resultset = 
            statement.executeQuery("select * from tableName where id = '" + id + "'") ; 

        if(!resultset.next()) {
            out.println("Sorry, could not find that publisher. " +
            "Please <A HREF='tryAgain.html'>try again</A>.");
        } else {
    %>

    <TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
           <TH>ID</TH>
           <TH>Name</TH>
           <TH>City</TH>
           <TH>State</TH>
           <TH>Country</TH>
       </TR>
       <TR>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </TD>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %> </TD>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(3) %> </TD>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(4) %> </TD>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(5) %> </TD>
       </TR>
   </TABLE>
   <BR>
   <% 
       } 
   %>
</BODY>
```

Comment: I dont want only refresh. I want data comes on jsp page at every 15 minutes.